# Consultar API de youtube desde jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, api

Es posible consumir esa API desde jquery?
Si lo pude hacer pero desde PHP, al realizar un post así en jquery:

```
 $.post("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VO7wstoK_gI&key=AIzaSyDolRu-zJQdK38G52I_rdxqRqruHx2PSBc&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status",
    function (respuesta) {
    alert(respuesta);
}).fail(function(p) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(p));
});
```

No me arroja nada, cabe aclarar que ya tengo la clave de la API y sí pude consumirla desde el backend, anteriormente he consultado una API del clima desde jquery, por eso creo que se podría.

En el alert de la función de error me sale esto:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"required\",\n    \"message\": \"Login Required\",\n    \"locationType\": \"header\",\n    \"location\": \"Authorization\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 401,\n  \"message\": \"Login Required\"\n }\n}\n","responseJSON":{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}},"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}
```

Comment: Qué te lanza? Tienes alguna validación de usuario? un token? Agrega más información en tu pregunta, saludos y bienvenido al sitio!

Comment: $.post("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VO7wstoK_gI&key=AIzaSyDolRu-zJQdK38G52I_rdxqRqruHx2PSBc&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status",
  function (respuesta) {
        alert(respuesta);
    }).fail(function(p) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(p));
   });                                 con esto, me arroja un error como de que no estoy autorizado, algo así, pero es que desde php con la misma url, me funciona bien.

Comment: edita tu pregunta con la información que me acabas de responder, click aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/58577/edit

Comment: Si te dice que no estás autorizado, en el backend, cómo haces la autorización?

Comment: En PHP solo hago esto: file_get_contents($video_url); y me devuelve todo, no hago ningún proceso de autenticación.

Comment: entonces, es probable que tengas el dominio vinculado con la autenticación y como lo trabajas en local, te lanza ese error, prueba subir tu javascript al server y ejecutarlo desde ahí :D

Comment: El script está en el server, al parecer eso no es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás utilizando `$.post`, usa `$.get` en su lugar y problema solucionado:

```js
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VO7wstoK_gI&key=AIzaSyDolRu-zJQdK38G52I_rdxqRqruHx2PSBc&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status",
    function (respuesta) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(respuesta));
}).fail(function(p) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(p));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias compañero funcionó excelente, si me podrías explicar un poco la diferencia te lo agradecería.

Comment: La verdad, no te puedo decir nada 100% seguro. Creo que puede ser porque estás haciendo una petición POST pero pasando los datos como GET, y eso podría crear algún tipo de conflicto. Pero no he encontrado ninguna página oficial que confirme eso.